# Has the character Shiva been confirmed to appear on The Walking Dead?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead

As people who read the comics know, there is a particularly unusual character who first appears in *The Walking Dead* shortly after Negan shows up.  Her name is Shiva, and she is

> a tiger.

Have the producers spoken about whether or not Shiva will appear on the show, presumably in Season 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There has been no confirmation, but there has clearly been discussion about it, and recent hints that it's possible.

It's an old discussion, but Kirkman and the producers of the show discussed it briefly at SDCC 2014. They spoke to [Zap2It](http://zap2it.com/2014/07/the-walking-dead-season-5-shiva-tiger-cast-producers/) about it.

> When asked about Ezekiel and Shiva, **Kirkman says, “I’m looking forward to the tiger as well. We’ll see. We’ll see.”**
>   There’s no chance that either character will show up on “The Walking Dead” Season 5, but if the show continues on its current path, then judging by the story in the books it may be time to introduce them by the show’s sixth season. And Kirkman isn’t the only one who’s excited.
>
> **“We want to cast Shiva,”** executive producer David Alpert says. “**We’re really excited to cast Shiva.** That will be awesome.”
>
> “Yeah, yeah, that will be fun,” fellow EP Gale Anne Hurd adds.

More recently, Scott Gimple [implied that it's possible](http://comicbook.com/2016/04/04/scott-gimple-teases-the-kingdom-in-the-walking-dead-season-7/).

> Can we have a real tiger? That's a great way to put the questions to me because it sort of corners me into a spoiler. I would say, in a really cheeky way, that we can have a lot of things and people are gonna have to wait and see. If I were just watching the show - I'd want to see that tiger."

Backing that up, Greg Nicotero all but confirmed that we've just met people from The Kingdom. From an interview with [EW](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/04/04/walking-dead-season-finale-greg-nicotero-negan/2):

> I don’t think they look similar to the people from The Kingdom, I think they look exactly like the people from The Kingdom. Again, our world is growing and it’s very, very exciting.